# Trying to run a Macro as part of a Rule in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros

I'm trying to run a Macro as part of a Rule in Outlook.  Here's my macro:

[image]

I then try to add it as a rule:

[image]

However, when I click on "a script", nothing shows up:

[image]

How can I make it run the macro I've created above?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research, I found an article that mentioned "The argument must by type MailItem or MeetingItem for the subroutine", it's recommended to modify your script or try to paste it in **ThisOutlookSession** part directly to check if the issue has any differences.

For your reference: [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)

Comment: That did the trick!  I guess whatever blog post I copied that code from was wrong, or maybe written for some other version of Outlook.  Who knows!